# Multiline regex match for only the start of a file

Tags: regex

How can I match a pattern only at the start of a file? In my particular usecase I have a script with a bunch of comments in the header and potential comments in the body, and I only want to remove the header comments.

```
# blah blah
# More blah
# Hello World
Actual stuff
# commented out stuff
More stuff
```

Should map to

```
Actual stuff
# commented out stuff
More stuff
```

The regex I've tried is `/^#.*$//mg`, but this will match the comments in the body as well. How can I restrict it to only the comments in the header? Additionally, I don't want to leave blank lines at the head of the file.

Comment: What tool are you using and how is header different from body?

Comment: @anubhava sed, and the header is different from the body because its in the head. In other words, the first non-`#` start of a line means end of header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With sed:

```
sed -n '1{:a;/^#/n;/^#/ba};p' file.txt
```

details:

```
1        # if the line number is 1
{        # do
  :a;    # define the label a
  /^#/n; # when the line begins with # load the next line in pattern space
  /^#/ba # if the "new" line begins with # go to label a
};
p        # print the line
```

With the `n` parameter, the lines are no more automatically printed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this awk:

```
awk '/^[^#]/{body=1} body' file
Actual stuff
# commented out stuff
More stuff
```